# Angular 7: Formvalidation, Validators.pattern not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I need a from validation for only matching integers. Therefore I use the `pattern`validator with regex (see below). Additionally the field should not be empty, so I added the `required` validator.

But the `pattern` error is never triggered. i read the angular docs and had a look to the source code of `pattern` and it still makes no sense to me. Additionally, I have read nearly every question on stackoverflow related to this topic. But I still can't figure out why the pattern is not working.

Maybe some of you guys might be able help me, thank you!

Here is my code component.ts:

```
// definition of the formcontrol
hours = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$'),
])

// for debugging
log() {
  console.log('required: ', this.hours.hasError('required'));
  console.log('pattern: ', this.hours.hasError('pattern'));
  console.log('Erros: ', this.hours.errors);
}
```

template:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [formControl]="hours" (input)="log()"
    placeholder="Anzahl der ausbezahlten Überstunden" type="number">
  <mat-error *ngIf="hours.hasError('required') && !hours.hasError('pattern')">
    Anzahl der Überstunden fehlt!
  </mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="!hours.hasError('required') && hours.hasError('pattern')">
    Anzahl muss eine Ganzzahl sein!
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Examples `inputValue=""`:

```
required: true
pattern: false
Error: Object { required: true }
```

`inputValue="1"`:

```
required:  false
pattern:  false
Error:  null
```

`inputValue="a"`:

```
required:  true
pattern:  false
Error: Object { required: true }
```

Comment: ^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$ use this regex in patter will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but still the same behaviour.Additionally this don't seams to be a valid pattern, to match my case [see here](https://regexr.com/49461)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it doesn't work with type="number",if you change it to type="text" it will work

Comment: Yup I was just writing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this way, normaly I use formBuilder here

*component*

```
 this.form = fb.group({
    age:[null , [Validators.required , Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]]
  })
```

*template*

```
<ng-container *ngIf="form.get('age').invalid && (form.get('age').touched || form.get('age').dirty)">
  <div *ngIf="form.get('age').hasError('required')">
    Required...
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.get('age').hasError('pattern')">
    Pattern Not valid
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-template-jmhska)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern) `required()` is of type `ValidationErrors`, and you're trying to create a FormControl using the `constructor(any, ValidatorFn[])`.

Have you tried using `Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$'), Validators.required])` ?

`Validators.compose()` returns a ValidatorFn that you can use to create a FormControl.

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168571/angular-2-multiple-validators) for an example and a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-template-ypnw4b).

Comment: I tried your advice, but no changes, still the same.

Comment: @malbarmawi stackblitz is working, if it doesn't work for you maybe a mix of both solutions do.